# How to fix very slow performance of filteredArrayUsingPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

```
for(NSInteger item = 0; item < items; item++){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(SELF.indexPath, $a, $a == %@).@count != 0", indexPath];

    NSArray *row = [[reticleMatrix filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] firstObject];

    MatrixElement *thisElement = nil;
    if(row){
        for(MatrixElement *element in row){
            if([element.indexPath isEqual:indexPath])
                thisElement = element;
        }
}
```

I have this code but it seems to slow down my scroll view. How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: use swift instead of obective-c better permance and swift is the future of apple

Comment: @FlorianNeiss How will that help, given the OP will still be calling an API implemented using Objective-C?

Comment: @Nana Can you please explain the structure of `reticleMatrix` and what this code is attempting to do?  It's likely you can dump the use of `NSPredicate` altogether.

Comment: Also that code involving `NSStringFromCGSize` is broken as well.  Even fractional changes in the size will mean new entries in `boundedMatrices`.  If you solve this performance issue then that should be next on your list.

Comment: NSPredicate is good, but is always slower than common block of code, instead of using a predicate try to use - indexOfObjectPassingTest: it requires just a block of code where you can put your logic. Posting the structure of the matrix would help.